# Upsert in junction records without duplicate creation

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object, junction-object

Have a junction  object that is a many to many relationship between two obejcts - Account and Publisher. As mentioned in the documentation I set the key in the Is there an easy way to upsert junction records without creating duplicates. Below is my code.  How do I specify an upsert if Account__c and Publisher__c are the same. Do I need to check for existing records via a select before inserting? Is there a way to make the platform aware that Account__c Publisher__c is unique for the set.

```
list<AccountPublisherAssociation__c> lstAssociations = new list<AccountPublisherAssociation__c>();

    for(string sPublisherId : lstOfPublisherIds){
        AccountPublisherAssociation__c accPublisherJunction = new AccountPublisherAssociation__c();            
    accPublisherJunction.Account__c = ParentId;
    accPublisherJunction.Publisher__c = sPublisherId;                       
        lstAssociations.add(accPublisherJunction);
    }

    upsert lstAssociations;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is to have an external ID on the junction object which would be a concatenation of Account and Publisher ids.

[Upserting Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_upsert.htm)

> To determine whether a record already exists, the upsert statement or
>   Database method uses the record’s ID as the key to match records, a
>   **custom external ID field**, or a standard field with the idLookup
>   attribute set to true.

Then when creating a record for  `AccountPublisherAssociation__c` calculate its value and assign to the record:

```
for(string sPublisherId : lstOfPublisherIds)
{
    AccountPublisherAssociation__c accPublisherJunction = new  AccountPublisherAssociation__c();            
    accPublisherJunction.Account__c = ParentId;
    accPublisherJunction.Publisher__c = sPublisherId;
    accPublisherJunction.Key__c = ParentId + '' + sPublisherId; //this is your External Id

    lstAssociations.add(accPublisherJunction);
}

upsert lstAssociations Key__c;
```

That will prevent from duplicates. Also check out this article for more details - [Import related records using an External ID](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000002783&type=1)

Comment: How can I set up an external ID field in salesforce lightning on a custom object. I do not see the options there.

Comment: You should create a custom text field and make it External Id. Go to Object Manager in Setup, find your object there, then find the Fields section and click New to create a custom field